# ¿Como evitar registros que sean iguales a 0 en una subconsulta?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

tengo la siguiente consulta donde me muestra las áreas y, con una sub-consulta, cuenta los activos fijos de estas:

```
SELECT
Nombre AS datos,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(IdActivoFijo)
    FROM
        c_activofijotemporal AS ac
    WHERE
        IdArea = a.IdArea
) AS series
FROM
c_area AS a
WHERE
a.IdPeriodo = 40
ORDER BY
a.Nombre;
```

me regresa los siguientes valores:

```
Académicos                    0
Administración                92
Amigos D. E                   0
Amigos P                      0
Amigos S.                     0
Archivo                       1
Arquitectura                  0
Comunicación                  0
Comunicación Social           0
Contabilidad                  0
Coordinación Operativa        0
Custodios                     139
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo hacer que no muestre los registros que sean igual a 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualización: Debes utilizar la cláusula [HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) para poder utilizar las funciones de agregación, y solamente mostrar aquellas cuyo SUM > 0. Vamos a agrupar utilizando el nombre:

```
SELECT  a.Nombre AS datos,
        sum(ac.IdActivoFijo) AS series
FROM    c_area AS a,
        c_activofijotemporal AS ac
WHERE   a.IdPeriodo = 40
AND     ac.IdArea = a.IdArea
GROUP BY (a.Nombre)
HAVING sum(ac.IdActivoFijo) >0
ORDER BY a.Nombre;
```

Hice pruebas con los siguientes datos:

```
create table c_area
(
Nombre varchar(50),
IdArea int,
IdPeriodo int
)

insert into c_area values ('uno', 1, 40)
insert into c_area values ('dos', 2, 40)
insert into c_area values ('tres', 3, 40)
insert into c_area values ('cuatro', 4, 40)
insert into c_area values ('cinco', 5, 40)
insert into c_area values ('seis', 6, 40)


create table c_activofijotemporal(
IdArea int,
IdActivoFijo int
)


insert into c_activofijotemporal values (1, 0)
insert into c_activofijotemporal values (2, 92)
insert into c_activofijotemporal values (3, 0)
insert into c_activofijotemporal values (4, 0)
insert into c_activofijotemporal values (5, 139)
insert into c_activofijotemporal values (6, 0)
```

Y los resultados fueron:

```
datos                                              series      
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- 
cinco                                              139         
dos                                                92          
(2 rows)Execution time: 0.034 seconds
```

Comment: las que el count era 0 ahora las pone como nulas para evitar que se muestren de igual forma tendría que ser en las áreas ?

Comment: @carlosbecerra revisa la respuesta, ya fue actualizada. Puedes probar directamente en tu consulta el HAVING, no es necesaria la subconsulta.

Comment: la probé justo como la pusiste y solo me marca un registro  Dirección 830

Comment: ¿Puedes actualizar tu pregunta e incluir las estructuras de ambas tablas? Gracias

Comment: @carlosbecerra actualice la respuesta, me estaba faltando un group by. Adicional, ¿estás seguro que es un conteo lo que necesitas? Creo que sería mas una suma de los activos fijos por área.

Comment: muchas gracias ya lo solucione con tu ayuda solo le cambie el sum por el count y salio perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Una opción seria agregar una subconsulta en el from el cual regrese datos y serie, para que el campo serie sea condicionado > 0

ejemplo:

```
   SELECT
    *
    FROM(
      SELECT
        Nombre AS datos,
        (
          SELECT
            COUNT(IdActivoFijo)
          FROM
            c_activofijotemporal AS ac
          WHERE
            IdArea = a.IdArea
        ) AS series
      FROM
      c_area AS a
      WHERE
      a.IdPeriodo = 40 
      ORDER BY
      a.Nombre
   ) as Tbl WHERE Tbl.series>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución más simple y óptima que se me ocurre es hacer un `inner join`.

```
SELECT   c_area.Nombre AS datos
       , count(ac.IdActivoFijo) AS series
  FROM c_area AS a
       inner join c_activofijotemporal AS ac on ac.IdArea = a.IdArea
 WHERE a.IdPeriodo = 40
 ORDER BY a.Nombre;
```

No hace falta aplicar otras condiciones, pues cuando un área no tenga registros en la tabla `c_activofijotemporal` automáticamente quedará excluida de los resultados, por ser un `inner join`.

Otra opción, si no puedes modificar tanto la consulta, es aplicar un `where` sobre la sub-consulta, pero ojo, que el optimizador de MySQL probablemente ejecute la sub-consulta dos veces por registro para poder hacer esto, por lo que el desempeño puede ser pobre si el volumen de datos es significativo:

```
SELECT
Nombre AS datos,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(IdActivoFijo)
    FROM
        c_activofijotemporal AS ac
    WHERE
        IdArea = a.IdArea
) AS series
FROM
c_area AS a
WHERE
a.IdPeriodo = 40
and (SELECT
        COUNT(IdActivoFijo)
    FROM
        c_activofijotemporal AS ac
    WHERE
        IdArea = a.IdArea) > 0
ORDER BY
a.Nombre;
```

Si ves, en este segundo caso, he trasladado la sub-consulta tal cual al `where` para filtrar aquellas que tengan valor 0.